# Cannot get sessionInfoListener on Whatsapp Embedded Signup

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, whatsapp-cloud-api

I'm trying to get sessionInfoListener to my Whatsapp Embedded login, but the return is being something like a callback info and code, meaning non json response. I'm receiving something like: data=cb=&code=<my_code_here>&origin=localhost=destination=

I'm doing my code as it follows:

```js
const launchWhatsAppSignup = async () => {
    window.fbq &&
      fbq("trackCustom", "WhatsAppOnboardingStart", {
        appId: <app_id>
        feature: "whatsapp_embedded_signup"
      });

    window.addEventListener("message", sessionInfoListener);

    FB.login(
      response => {
        if (response.authResponse) {
          const code = response.authResponse.code;
        } else {
          console.log("User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.");
        }
      },
      {
        config_id: <config_id>
        response_type: "code",
        override_default_response_type: true,
        extras: {
          sessionInfoVersion: 2,
          feature: "whatsapp_embedded_signup"
        }
      }
    );
  };


const sessionInfoListener = event => {
    if (event.origin !== "https://www.facebook.com") return;
    try {
      const data = JSON.parse(event.data);
      if (data.type === "WA_EMBEDDED_SIGNUP") {
        // if user finishes the Embedded Signup flow
        if (data.event === "FINISH") {
          const { phone_number_id, waba_id } = data.data;
        }
        // if user cancels the Embedded Signup flow
        else {
          const { current_step } = data.data;
        }
      }
    } catch {
      // Don’t parse info that’s not a JSON
      console.log("Non JSON Response", event.data);
    }
  };

  window.addEventListener("message", sessionInfoListener);

  window.launchWhatsAppSignup = launchWhatsAppSignup;
};
```

I already added the feature: "whatsapp_embedded_signup" in extras, but still receiving the same message.

Can someone help me with it?